# Show that the set $\{v_1, v_2, ... , v_{k-1}\}$ cannot be a basis for V .

Tags: linear-algebra, span

Let $\{v_1, v_2, ... , v_k\}$ be a linearly independent set of vectors in a vector space V .
Show that the set $\{v_1, v_2, ... , v_{k-1}\}$ cannot be a basis for V .

I am trying to prove this by contradiction.

- Suppose $\{v_1, v_2, ... , v_{k-1}\}$ is a basis for V. Then span of this set is equal to V. So any vector in V can be written as a unique linear combination as the vectors in this set.
- $v_k$ belongs to V thus $v_k= c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + ... + c_{k-1}v_{k-1}$.

I'm stuck now, how can I use linear independence to show a contradiction?

Comment: So $c_1v_1+…c_{k-1}v_{k-1}+v_k=0$ but the coefficient in front of $v_k$ is not zero, contradict with linearly independent assumption.

Comment: It's that simple... I feel stupid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As  you have already assumed that $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$  is a basis for $V$ so $v_k$ can not written as linear combination of $\{v_1,..,v_{k-1} \}$.Hence Contradiction.